# How can I call multiple constructors using inheritance in java?

Tags: java

I'm trying to code constructor Square with one parameter, s (side). This inputted side should set the length and width of a square to its value. Rectangle is a superclass of square and takes l and w (length and width) as parameters. How can I set the value of s to l (length) and w (width)?

```
{
    public Square()
    {
        super();
    }
    public Square(int s)
    {
       //?????
    }
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(3,5);
        r.draw();
        // 4. Uncomment these to test
         Square s1 = new Square();
         s1.draw();
         Square s = new Square(3);
         s.draw();
     }
}
```

Comment: `super(s, s)`? Be careful if the fields are not final. A square is a rectangle iff the rectangle is immutable. If mutable, there's no guarantee it will remain square.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. I'm still new to all this java stuff. Also, nice name

Comment: Hey David, just a tidbit, could you include the whole class code like the `public class Square` declaration? You are calling `super()` so I suppose `Square` has a parent class? If yes, could you also add it to the question so that others can visualize the whole solution? Thank you

Comment: I am pretty sure super() is built into java and refers to the super class, which in this case is rectangle.The two values represented by s fit into a 2 parameter constructor, containing l and w (I think).